# primefaces editor font size

Tags: primefaces, editor

Primefaces has a fancy HTML editor `<p:editor>`.
Is there a way to change `font-size` or apply style in general to the text user enters inside Primefaces' editor? For example, I applied `style=""` as shown below but it does not work.

```
<p:editor id="editor" style="font-size: 26px;font-family:verdana" value="#{eventController.eventUI.desc}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces editor use iframe, and iframe use one page inside, so you have to change css for that page.
You can try:

```
<h:form id="form">  
        <p:editor id="eid" value="nothing"/>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#form\\:eid').find('iframe').contents().find('body').css({
                    'font-size': '10px',
                    'color' : 'blue'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion really helped. I also had to make sure that iframe was ready before I could get an access of `<body>` content. `$('iframe').ready(function() {
                $('iframe').contents().find('body').css({
                    'font-size' : '16px',
                    'font-family' : 'verdana'
                });
                
            });`